# Django : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: django, django-forms, foreign-keys

I'm getting a little problem between models and forms in my Django project.
I created a new app : `Divorce`

My **models.py** file looks like :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from Identity.models import Person
from Mariage.models import Acte_Mariage
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


class Acte_Divorce(models.Model):

    fk_epoux = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='EpouxDivorce', verbose_name='Epoux', null=False)
    fk_epouse = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='EpouseDivorce', verbose_name='Epouse', null=False)

    fk_temoin1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 1 Divorce+', verbose_name='Temoin 1', null=True)
    fk_temoin2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 2 Divorce+', verbose_name='Temoin 2', null=True)
    fk_temoin3 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 3 Divorce+', verbose_name='Temoin 3', null=True)
    fk_temoin4 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 4 Divorce+', verbose_name='Temoin 4', null=True)

    mairie = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Mairie', default='  ')

    fk_mariage = models.ForeignKey(Acte_Mariage, related_name='ID', verbose_name="ID", null=False, default= '0')

    divorce_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Date du mariage (optionnel)')
    divorce_heure = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Heure du mariage (optionnel)')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    utilisateur = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="utilisateur", default=" ")
```

As you can see, I have two fields with two different Foreign_Key : the first one is pointing to `Person model` and the second one to `Acte_Mariage model`.

Now, I have in my Divorce application a **forms.py** file :

```
class CustomLabelModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._label_from_instance = kwargs.pop('label_func', force_text)
        super(CustomLabelModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return self._label_from_instance(obj)

class Acte_Divorce_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    fk_epoux = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(sex = "Masculin"), required=False, label = "Epoux", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number),  empty_label=None)
    fk_epouse = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(sex = "Feminin"), required=False, label = "Epouse", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number), empty_label=None)

    fk_mariage = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Acte_Mariage.objects.filter(), label="N° Acte Mariage", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s' % (obj.id, obj.fk_epoux, obj.fk_epouse))

    fk_temoin1 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(Q(sex='Masculin') | Q(sex='Feminin')), required=False, label = "Témoin 1", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number), empty_label=None)
    fk_temoin2 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(Q(sex='Masculin') | Q(sex='Feminin')), required=False, label = "Témoin 2", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number), empty_label=None)
    fk_temoin3 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(Q(sex='Masculin') | Q(sex='Feminin')), required=False, label = "Témoin 3", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number), empty_label=None)
    fk_temoin4 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Person.objects.filter(Q(sex='Masculin') | Q(sex='Feminin')), required=False, label = "Témoin 4", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity, obj.social_number), empty_label=None)

    mairie = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=Mairie.objects.using('default').last().city.encode('utf-8'))
    utilisateur = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta :
        model = Acte_Divorce
        fields = ['fk_epoux', 'fk_epouse', 'fk_mariage', 'fk_temoin1', 'fk_temoin2', 'fk_temoin3', 'fk_temoin4', 'divorce_date', 'divorce_heure', 'mairie', 'utilisateur']
        widgets = {'country': CountrySelectWidget()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(Acte_Divorce_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, value in self.fields.iteritems() :
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-fields'})
```

In `class Acte_Divorce_Form(forms.ModelForm)`, I have `fk_mariage` with a label function.

If I write :

```
fk_mariage = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Acte_Mariage.objects.filter(), label="N° Acte Mariage", label_func=lambda obj: '%s' % (obj.id))
```

It works, but I want to display two more fields :

```
fk_mariage = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Acte_Mariage.objects.filter(), label="N° Acte Mariage", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s' % (obj.id, obj.fk_epoux, obj.fk_epouse))
```

And now I'm getting this error : `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

By which expression I need to replace `%s` for `obj.fk_epoux` and `obj.fk_epouse` ? Both fields gives me a number.

Thank you

**EDIT :**

My model from Mariage application :

```
class Acte_Mariage(models.Model):

    fk_epoux = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Epoux', verbose_name='Epoux', null=False)
    fk_epouse = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Epouse', verbose_name='Epouse', null=False)

    fk_father_husband = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Pere Epoux+', verbose_name='Pere Epoux', null=False)
    fk_mother_husband = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Mere Epoux+', verbose_name='Mere Epoux', null=False)
    fk_father_wife = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Pere Epouse+', verbose_name='Pere Epouse', null=False)
    fk_mother_wife = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Mere Epouse+', verbose_name='Mere Epouse', null=False)

    fk_temoin1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 1+', verbose_name='Temoin 1', null=True)
    fk_temoin2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 2+', verbose_name='Temoin 2', null=True)
    fk_temoin3 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 3+', verbose_name='Temoin 3', null=True)
    fk_temoin4 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='Temoin 4+', verbose_name='Temoin 4', null=True)

    mairie = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Mairie', default='  ')

    mariage_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Date du mariage (optionnel)')
    mariage_heure = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Heure du mariage (optionnel)')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    utilisateur = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="utilisateur", default=" ")
```

Comment: Your model does not allow for same sex marriage?

Comment: Please share your model `Acte_Mariage`

Comment: @MichielB Not for the moment because the country where this project will be installed doesn't allow same sex marriage. It could be a next update ;)

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated my question ;)

Comment: Your code `'%s %s %s' % (obj.id, obj.fk_epoux, obj.fk_epouse)` looks ok. If you got an error, then I think your code was something slightly different.

Comment: @Alasdair Pretty strange because I exactly copy/paste my code ^^ I tried @FazilZaid's answer and it works with `{}.format()`

Comment: Sure, switching to `format` is ok, but the `%s` code looks ok. Perhaps you didn't restart the server after changing the code, so it wasn't actually running the code you copied and pasted.

Comment: Maybe you're right. At least, if i'm using `format` it's rather modern because it comes from Python 3.X and not 2.X ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
fk_mariage = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Acte_Mariage.objects.filter(), label="N° Acte Mariage", label_func=lambda obj: '{} {} {}'.format(str(obj.id), str(obj.fk_epoux), str(obj.fk_epouse)))
```

An

Comment: Oh yes I used your solution and it works perfectly ! But why I have to specify format for each object with `{}` and not with `%s` ?

Comment: `%s`was in python 2.x, python3 supports `{}` for string formatting

Comment: Pretty strange because I'm using Python 2.7 oO

Comment: Would you please do me a favour and mark the answer as selected, then?

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes before validate it

Comment: You needed to convert the ids into string before any formatting done, that's why the error message raised.

Comment: @FazilZaid you do not need to convert integers to strings. Both `"{} {} {}".format(1,2,3)` and `"%s %s %s".format(1,2,3)` work in Python 2.7 and 3.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. I just tested it. Sorry for the false commentation. I don't know why it didn't work out for him. I just posted what I knew, glad it helped him.